# how to access every key value in a json file and return them as a list in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a list element that looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "leaf101": {
            "node_id": "101",
            "node_name": "leaf101",
            "pod_id": "1"
        },
        "leaf102": {
            "node_id": "102",
            "node_name": "leaf102",
            "pod_id": "1"
        },
        "spine103": {
            "node_id": "103",
            "node_name": "spine103",
            "pod_id": "1"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm trying to give a list back to list them as variables in the Active choices parameter in Jenkins. My script looks as follows:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def list = []

File textfile= new File("/var/lib/jenkins/test/vars/nodes.json")
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson = slurper.parse(textfile)

parsedJson.each {
    list.add (it.node_name.toString())
}

return list;
```

Which returns nothing. If I type `return parsedJson` at the end I get the entire file content as one variable.
How can I only return the key values like "leaf01,leaf02..."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parsedJson.each {
    list.add (it.node_name.toString())
}
```

I think the problem with that is that `it` is the outer object which contains `[leaf101:[node_id:101, node_name:leaf101, pod_id:1], leaf102:[node_id:102, node_name:leaf102, pod_id:1], spine103:[node_id:103, node_name:spine103, pod_id:1]]`, so `it.node_name` is not going to work.  You will need to iterate a layer deeper into the model.

For example, this will yield the result you expected:

```
    parsedJson.each { obj ->
        obj.each { k, v ->
            list.add v.node_name
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, Just for me to understand correctly can you explain the 
`{ obj ->
        obj.each { k, v ->` part to me. I'm still trying to learn groovy. Thank you!

Comment: When you invoke `.each` on a `Map` the `Closure` you pass as an argument will be executed once for each entry in the `Map`.  If the `Closure` accepts 1 parameter, the argument passed into the `Closure` each time will be a `Map.Entry` object.  If the `Closure` accepts 2 parameters, the first parameter will be the key for the `Map.Entry` and the second parameter will be the value from same.

Comment: Try this for clarification: `[name: 'Jeff', favoriteLang: 'Groovy', town: 'STL'].each { k, v -> println "$k is $v"}`